# Macro to transfer data from Access to Excel I am facing problem

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am new to excel macro access I have created a macro in access database that transfer data/query from MS Access database to excel.
My code/macro was working fine till demo. But now I encounter a problem that is after the data is transferred to excel then value in column B should change the values for which I have updated conditions within for loop as below... Now it debugs at the first value FXV, in excel it does not changes the value to FFJ as I coded. However, when it is FLB it used to change the value properly but now it does not for FXV and macro becomes slow. can someone help in fixing this?

[image: Here is where it debugs]

Below is my complete code: - So macro transfer data from access to excel then in excel it should change the values present in column B which I have coded within FOR loop it was working but now it is not I don know why? can any1 help me on this please.....
The problem is in For loop when I change the range i = 2 to 999 it will run and paste the data but it does not change the value of FXV to FFJ...
if I change the range for i = 1 to 999 or for i = 0 to 999 it will debug as shown below.... please help....

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command0_Click()
ExportToExcel
End Sub

Public Sub ExportToExcel()

Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim wbtarget As Workbook

Dim FinalExp As QueryDef
Dim rsFinalExp As Recordset

Dim i As Integer


'Set up reference to the query to export

Set FinalExp = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("FinalExp")

'Debug.Print FinalExp.SQL

'Set up the parameter
'Execute the query

Set rsFinalExp = FinalExp.OpenRecordset()

'programetically reference exel

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'set ref to the export workbook (Paste the Excel Path)

Set wbtarget = xl.Workbooks.Open("path.xlsm")

'use paste from recordset to put in excel sheet
wbtarget.Worksheets("SampleFile").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsFinalExp


'Replace the FWD_Code's in column 2
 For i = 0 To 9999

If Worksheets("SampleFile").Range("B" & i).Value = "FXV" Then
      Worksheets("SampleFile").Range("B" & i).Value = "FFJ"
 
   ElseIf Worksheets("SampleFile").Range("B" & i).Value = "FAM" Then
            Worksheets("SampleFile").Range("B" & i).Value = "FST"
 
   ElseIf Worksheets("SampleFile").Range("B" & i).Value = "FLB" Then
            Worksheets("SampleFile").Range("B" & i).Value = "FST"
            
 End If
 
 Next


'save workbook
wbtarget.Save

wbtarget.Close

Set wbtarget = Nothing
Set xl = Nothing

Set FinalExp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no `B0`

Comment: where it should be

Comment: Rather than looping the cells that you have just copied, it would be more efficient to do the changes in the recordset (possibly using `IIf` or using a lookup table). Also, if you ever have more than 999 records, your code won't work as expected - you should find out how many times you need to loop (either using `.RecordCount` or `ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`). And if you only export 2 rows, then looping 999 rows is pointless.

Answer (score 3):

You'd be better off declaring a worksheet variable, and using `Select Case`

```vb
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set wbtarget = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\path.xlsm")
Set ws = wbtarget.Worksheets("SampleFile") 

ws.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsFinalExp

For i = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    With ws.Cells(i, "B")
         Debug.Print .Parent.Name, .Address(), .Value '<<< for debugging
         Select Case .Value
             Case "FXV": .Value = "FFJ"
             Case "FAM": .Value = "FST"
             Case "FLB": .Value = "FST"
         End Select
     End With 
Next i

wbtarget.Close True 'save on close
```

Comment: No its not working macro does not change the value 
             Case "FXV": .Value = "FFJ"
             Case "FAM": .Value = "FST"
             Case "FLB": .Value = "FST"

Comment: have you tried debugging to see where the problem is?

Comment: the macro executes without any error it transfers the data but does not replace the value..

Comment: Seems like the values are not triggering any replacement?  See my edit above.

Comment: No it not... It transfers data from Access to Excel but does not changes the value in the Excel file....this is the code that I use it does not give any bug also see above I have copy-pasted the complete code

Comment: If you need to add code please edit your question and add it there